# Ionic Angular Standalone ion-icon are not showing at all

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using ionic 7 angular standalone but ion icons are not showing at all in web. i have also tried to add these scripts in index.html .

[image]

here is my code

```html
<ion-row>
  <ion-col size="2" class="ion-text-center">
    <h6 class="m-0 f-md">4:00</h6>
    <h4 class="m-0 f-md bold">PM</h4>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="6">
    <div>
      <ion-text class="f-md bold">Launch with Juile</ion-text>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ion-text class="f-md">Family</ion-text>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="2"> 
    <div>
      <ion-icon name="star" color="danger"></ion-icon>
    </div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

This is my package.json dependencies

```html
 "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.2",
    "@capacitor/android": "5.7.4",
    "@capacitor/app": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/core": "5.7.4",
    "@capacitor/haptics": "5.0.7",
    "@capacitor/keyboard": "5.0.8",
    "@capacitor/status-bar": "5.0.7",
    "@ionic/angular": "^7.5.0",
    "ionicons": "^7.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "swiper": "^11.1.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
```